# Ionic 3 inapp browser open byte array

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a question related to ionic 3/angular 4 hybrid mobile app.

is it possible to view/display any **memory stream/byte stream** whichever mime type like **.png/jpeg etc**.,. from the api whatever i receive in ionic inapp browser?
only the stream data?

or is it only intented to **open the url's**? does it support memory stream data ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a external page lets say you have created a page https://yourdomain.com/loadpic/{id}.

You can then use this page to pass the variable id or any identifier and show the image or anything,

INAPP BROWSER will process this page also

Comment: my bad;( i worked with this same bfr... now working fine

Answer (score 0):

If in-app browser isn't a hard requirement here, then the answer is yes, you can view/display various mime types via byte arrays/streams in an ionic/angular hybrid mobile app.  I would suggest using something like the File Opener cordova plugin to assist with viewing/opening, which has a nice [ionic native wrapper](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file-opener/).

You'll likely be dealing with JS Blobs here.  You'll want to save the Blob as a file to the device, then use File Opener to open/view it.  If your hybrid app is also hosted as a web app, then you'll need a web-specific approach in that scenario.  Some sample code is below for the native side (assuming no web needed).  It uses the File/File Opener Cordova plugins.

```
var blob = new Blob([res], { type: 'application/pdf' });

//Determine a native file path to save to
let filePath = (this.appConfig.isNativeAndroid) ? this.file.externalRootDirectory : this.file.cacheDirectory;

//Write the file
this.file.writeFile(filePath, fileName, blob, { replace: true }).then((fileEntry: FileEntry) => {

  console.log("File created!");

  //Open with File Opener plugin
  this.fileOpener.open(fileEntry.toURL(), data.type)
    .then(() => console.log('File is opened'))
    .catch(err => console.error('Error openening file: ' + err));
})
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error("Error creating file: " + err);
    throw err;  //Rethrow - will be caught by caller
  });
```

Comment: hi,thank you for response..here in my case i shouldn't save  any file in local.. and just using the stream which i received i need to display ...but inapp is not hard requirement..